# Location service giving me null on some phones android

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, location

I created a service for getting user Location which I am calling from my main thread. Now, this service is getting my location not just from gps, but also from network. Why is it getting user Location on some phones and on some phones it doesnt?

Here is my service class:

```
 import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.List;


public class LocationService extends Service implements LocationListener {

    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public String providerNow;
    private List<String> providers;

    public Location location;

    public LocationService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);

        providerNow = (GetProvider());
    }

    public Location getLocation() {

        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(providerNow);
        return location;
    }


    public String GetProvider() {

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(2);

        providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);
        String providerToSend = providers.get(1);

        return providerToSend;

    }

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.i("TestMap", "onBind");
        //TODO for communication return IBinder implementation
        return null;
    }


    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Static.location = location;

        if (location != null) {
            Log.d("Lat", String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
            Log.d("Lon", String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
            Static.latitude = location.getLatitude();
            Static.longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        providerNow = (GetProvider());
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        providerNow = (GetProvider());
    }
}
```

Here is the code from main thread where I am calling this service:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);
        proveraInterneta();



        getSizeOfTheScreen();
    }
```

Comment: 1) In case of disabled GPS providers array length is 1 and you'll have crash  in GetProvider() function 2) Please add your code where you initiate service

Comment: @Hoochwo added the code, so, what can be a problem?

Answer (score 2):

Here are the two suggestions for the issue you are facing:

- As per coding, make use of the Google's ***[Fused Location API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi)***. FusedLocationProviderApi can be accessed via LocationServices as below,

  ```
  private FusedLocationProviderApi fusedLocationProviderApi = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi;
  ```

FusedLocationProviderApi requires the GoogleApiClient instance to get the Location and it can be obtained as below.

```
googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(locationActivity)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
```

- Secondly, from device perspective make sure that the GPS is turned on all the devices under test.
- Last but not the least, check if this permission is added in the manifest.

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  ```

Take a look at this [tutorial](http://javapapers.com/android/android-location-fused-provider/) for more reference.

Comment: tried that, its not finding me when gps is turned off

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your code, when you call getLocation method then obtain latest location from currently working provider (or latest enabled provider). When you enable a provider, it's not guaranteed getting location from getLocation method.

if i call getLastKnownLocation("gps") right after making enabled gps provider, it so normal getting null result. Because gps provider must fire onLocationChanged method at least one time, so i have to wait for gps fix. Also this scenario is same for network provider too.

Calling getLastKnownLocation("a provider") method without being sure about the provider is fixed, will give you unreliable(old location) or null result. In this case, if some phones doesn't give null, it means these devices have cached location for current provider or they are lucky because the provider is warmed up already